# Trouble with subprocess.check_output()

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm having some strange issues using `subprocess.check_output()`. At first I was just using `subprocess.call()` and everything was working fine. However when I simply switch out `call()` for `check_output()`, I receive a strange error.

Before code (works fine):

```
def execute(hosts):
''' Using psexec, execute the batch script on the list of hosts '''
successes = []
wd = r'c:\\'
file = r'c:\\script.exe'
for host in hosts:
    res = subprocess.call(shlex.split(r'psexec \\\\%s -e -s -d -w %s %s' % (host,wd,file)))
    if res.... # Want to check the output here
        successes.append(host)
    return successes
```

After code (doesn't work):

```
def execute(hosts):
''' Using psexec, execute the batch script on the list of hosts '''
successes = []
wd = r'c:\\'
file = r'c:\\script.exe'
for host in hosts:
    res = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(r'psexec \\\\%s -e -s -d -w %s %s' % (host,wd,file)))
    if res.... # Want to check the output here
    successes.append(host)
return successes
```

This gives the error:
[image: Error]

I couldnt redirect this because the program hangs here and I can't ctrl-c out. Any ideas why this is happening? What's the difference between subprocess.call() and check_output() that could be causing this?

Here is the additional code including the multiprocessing portion:

```
PROCESSES = 2
host_sublists_execute = [.... list of hosts ... ]
poolE = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=PROCESSES)
success_executions = poolE.map(execute,host_sublists_execute)
success_executions = [entry for sub in success_executions for entry in sub]
poolE.close()
poolE.join()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Both code samples are the same. Looks like you made a copy/paste error...

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that - fixed. Only difference is call > check_output

Comment: Is `execute` running inside of a `multiprocessing.Pool`? Are you trying to do a `raise CalledProcessError` later in `execute`? If so, please include that code.

Comment: Yes I am using multiprocessing, I will update the original code with everything else

Comment: Also included the rest of execute function, all I do is track successes and return them. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's odd, the exception you're getting appears to be a problem raising `CalledProcessError` (not enough arguments being passed to the constructor). Can you try calling `execute` without doing it via `multiprocessing`, so you can get a full traceback?

Comment: do you understand that `call()` returns a `returncode` (an integer) and `check_output()` returns the captured output (a string)?

Answer (score 5):

You are encountering [Python Issue 9400](http://bugs.python.org/issue9400).

There is a key distinction you have to understand about `subprocess.call()` vs `subprocess.check_output()`. `subprocess.call()` will execute the command you give it, then *provide you with the return code*. On the other hand, `subprocess.check_output()` returns the program's output to you in a string, but it tries to do you a favor and check the program's return code and *will raise an exception* (`subprocess.CalledProcessError`) if the program did not execute successfully (returned a non-zero return code).

When you call `pool.map()` with a multiprocessing pool, it will try to propagate exceptions in the subprocesses back to main and raise an exception there. Apparently there is an issue with how the `subprocess.CalledProcessError` exception class is defined, so the pickling fails when the multiprocessing library tries to propagate the exception back to main.

The program you're calling is returning a non-zero return code, which makes `subprocess.check_output()` raise an exception, and `pool.map()` can't handle it properly, so you get the `TypeError` that results from the failed attempt to retrieve the exception.

As a side note, the definition of `subprocess.CalledProcessError` must be really screwed up, because if I open my 2.7.6 terminal, import subprocess, and manuallly raise the error, I still get the `TypeError`, so I don't think it's merely a pickling problem.